# MS Excel : How to divide income range into groups?

Tags: excel, group-by, excel-2007, excel-formula

I am having a table that has 2500 rows.

There is a column `Income` which has the values in the form of ranges.

```
10000 - 14999
100000 - 149999
15000 - 19999
150000 - 174999
175000 - 199999
20000 - 24999
200000 - 249999
25000 - 29999
250000+
30000 - 34999
35000 - 39999
40000 - 44999
45000 - 49999
50000 - 54999
55000 - 59999
60000 - 64999
65000 - 74999
75000 - 99999
Under 10000
```

Some are blank cells.

I need to create a new column based on this

```
1.$ 30000- $50000- Low Income Group
2.$ 51000-$125,000-Medium Income Group
3.$ 125,00-$ 250,000-Higher Medium Income Group
4.$ 251,000- $ 500,000-Donor Group
5.$ 500,000 and Over- Bigger Donor Group
```

I am not good at Excel, can someone please guide me through?

It would be appreciated, I am using Excel 2010

Comment: do you have `10000 - 14999` in ONE cell??

Comment: also do you have ranges fixed? e.g. you have only `10000 - 14999` or you can have `10000 - 11999`, `10000 - 12999`

Comment: yes @FahimParkar  , I have 10000 - 14999  in one cell :(

the ranges that i have are 

`10000 - 14999
100000 - 149999
15000 - 19999
150000 - 174999
175000 - 199999
20000 - 24999
200000 - 249999
25000 - 29999
250000+
30000 - 34999
35000 - 39999
40000 - 44999
45000 - 49999
50000 - 54999
55000 - 59999
60000 - 64999
65000 - 74999
75000 - 99999
Under 10000

`

Comment: you can use vlookup here

Comment: @FahimParkar - How to use that ?

What i thought is if i could some how take the average of the cell by evaluating it . and then some how use the IF condition and see if the values lies in which range according to that put the apt Tag.

Not sure if it would work

Comment: see my answer... hope this is what you want...

Comment: If you need to do calculation then you would need to write MACRO. I don't know about excel macros...

Comment: let me know if you can accept two ranges as lower range and higher range i.e. 10000 in one Cell and 14999 in another cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have input as shown below Cell A and you want output as shown in Cell B & C. Then you need to write what I have in Cell D, Cell E & Cell F.

To get output as shown in Cell B & C you need to write below.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$20,2,FALSE)` in Cell B1 & `=VLOOKUP(A1,$D$1:$F$19,3,FALSE)` in Cell C1. The drag that formula acorss column.

```
+ Cell A         +  Cell B     +    Cell C       ++      Cell D        +     Cell D     +     Cell F        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+10000 - 14999   + US Dollar 1 +  Income Group 1 ++   10000 - 14999    +  US Dollar 1   +   Income Group 1  +
+10000 - 14999   + US Dollar 1 +  Income Group 1 ++   100000 - 149999  +  US Dollar 2   +   Income Group 2  +
+10000 - 14999   + US Dollar 1 +  Income Group 1 ++   15000 - 19999    +  US Dollar 3   +   Income Group 3  +
+100000 - 149999 + US Dollar 2 +  Income Group 2 ++   150000 - 174999  +  US Dollar 4   +   Income Group 4  +
+25000 - 29999   + US Dollar 8 +  Income Group 8 ++   175000 - 199999  +  US Dollar 5   +   Income Group 5  +
+250000+         + US Dollar 9 +  Income Group 9 ++   20000 - 24999    +  US Dollar 6   +   Income Group 6  +
+                +             +                 ++   200000 - 249999  +  US Dollar 7   +   Income Group 7  +
+                +             +                 ++   25000 - 29999    +  US Dollar 8   +   Income Group 8  +
+                +             +                 ++   250000+          +  US Dollar 9   +   Income Group 9  +
+                +             +                 ++   30000 - 34999    +  US Dollar 10  +   Income Group 10 +
+                +             +                 ++   35000 - 39999    +  US Dollar 11  +   Income Group 11 +
+                +             +                 ++   40000 - 44999    +  US Dollar 12  +   Income Group 12 +
+                +             +                 ++   45000 - 49999    +  US Dollar 13  +   Income Group 13 +
+                +             +                 ++   50000 - 54999    +  US Dollar 14  +   Income Group 14 +
+                +             +                 ++   55000 - 59999    +  US Dollar 15  +   Income Group 15 +
+                +             +                 ++   60000 - 64999    +  US Dollar 16  +   Income Group 16 +
+                +             +                 ++   65000 - 74999    +  US Dollar 17  +   Income Group 17 +
+                +             +                 ++   75000 - 99999    +  US Dollar 18  +   Income Group 18 +
+                +             +                 ++   Under 10000      +  US Dollar 19  +   Income Group 19 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**NOTE**

You need to update column E & F as per your requirement. Let me know your email id if you need the sample excel that I have created.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thanks @fahim For the Quick response .
My Email ID is aditya169@gmail.com  It would be great if you could send me the excel sheet.

Comment: 2nd Question
Did you manually Make these + Symbols and formate it so well?  :)

Comment: let me know if this is what you want.... also accept answer if I answered your question...

Comment: I dont understand =VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$20,2,FALSE) & =VLOOKUP(A1,$D$1:$F$19,3,FALSE) 

But as the Diagram , I need the coloum C to be created depending on which income range they are in. 


If cell A1 has 10000 - 14999  then Cell c1 should automatically get INCOME Group1

So on....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7882/discussion-between-adi-mathur-and-fahim-parkar)

Comment: = One small question too... Is there some way to evaluate the Cell too ? If i put an = then the value is evaluated...

Putting = in each cell manually is not possible so any way for doing this too?